# Two columns centered content with divider

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I can't seem to get this one right. I am building a **mobile app** (ionic / AngularJS), and I want a bottom bar (footer), divided into two boxes with a gap in the middle. It each side would have the text centered directly in the middle of it.

It would fit **full width** (100%).

[image: What I'm trying to do]
[image]

I have created it in a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MYwPt/112/

My HTML:

```
<div class="faketab">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>LEFT BOX</td>
            <td class="centerpiece"></td>
            <td>RIGHT BOX</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.faketab
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: horizontal;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    border-color: #b2b2b2;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #b2b2b2, #b2b2b2 50%, transparent 50%);
    color: #4d4d4d;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 49px; */
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    background-size: 0;
}
.faketab table tr td {
    width: 2em;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size:18px;
}
.centerpiece{
    border-left: 0.1em solid black;
}
```

Comment: I have removed some of the code from your fiddle. Do you want like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/MYwPt/114/

Comment: I would advise against using tables unless there was a specific need. Something like this would be much cleaner. https://jsfiddle.net/gbvcq7p7/

Comment: For future users to know, please accept an answer, if any, that solve your question best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cleaned up and simple structure that does all you ask.

Edit: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/v8021u8e/1/) has prefixed `flex` attributes.

Edit 2: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/v8021u8e/3/) has `display: table` instead of `flex` and will work down to IE8.

```css
.faketab {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 2px 2px;           /* space around buttons */
}
.faketab > div:first-child {
  margin-right: 2em;            /* space between boxes */
}
.faketab > div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size:18px;
  border: 2px solid #b2b2b2;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="faketab">
  <div>BUTTON</div>
  <div>BUTTON 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks- and this is suitable for mobile/all browsers?

Comment: @Yian Above sample works on all newer browsers (mobile or desktop) that support the newest flexbox. The updated fiddle link sample is prefixed to support also IE10 and Safari 7/8, but if you want to support even older such as IE8/9, flexbox can't be used as it does not work on those older one's. So how far back do you want to go?

Comment: @Yian I added a second fiddle link just in case you want to support browsers that don't know `flex`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use divs. You need to set only the display property to inline and the float to left. For the text text-align: center.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.faketab{
  display:inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  border-top:1px solid;
}

.tabs{
  float:left;
  width:49.5%;
  text-align:center;
}

.tabs:hover{
  color: #B0B0B0;
}

.vertical{
  float:left;
  border-left:1px solid;
  height:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="faketab">
  <div class="tabs">LEFT BOX</div>
  <span class="vertical"></span>
  <div class="tabs">RIGHT BOX</div>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to add `display: table-cell` for each `td` and then change the code like the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="faketab">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>LEFT BOX</td>
            <td>RIGHT BOX</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.faketab table tr td {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size:18px;
}

.faketab table tr td:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MYwPt/113/)**

You can do the same result with less markup and cleaner code that could work on mobile.

**1. `<a>` links**

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs tabs--block">
  <a href="#" class="tabs__item">Left tab title</a>
  <a href="#" class="tabs__item">right tab title</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.tabs--block .tabs__item {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabs--block .tabs__item:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.tabs--block:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.tabs--block .tabs__item {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabs--block .tabs__item:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**2. Flexbox**

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs tabs--flex">
<a href="#" class="tabs__item">Left tab title</a>
  <a href="#" class="tabs__item">right tab title</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs--flex {
  display: flex;
}

.tabs--flex .tabs__item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabs--flex .tabs__item:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadeed/pen/2323ceba2f9d4878f6498830a32a1bb7?editors=010)**

Comment: Thanks- this works on mobile, but the middle/center part moves relative to the text in the box (ie if one has long text, the middle will change its' position). Can you re-do this fixing the problem?

Comment: @Yian Can you check this please? http://jsfiddle.net/MYwPt/120/ If it's ok, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Used to this**  CSS **[border-spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp)** Property

```
table{border-spacing: 0;}
```

```css
table{border-spacing: 0;}

.faketab
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: horizontal;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    border-color: #b2b2b2;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #b2b2b2, #b2b2b2 50%, transparent 50%);
    color: #4d4d4d;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 49px; */
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    background-size: 0;
}
.faketab table tr td {
    width: 2em;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size:18px;
}
.centerpiece{
    border-left: 0.1em solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="faketab">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>LEFT BOX</td>
            <td class="centerpiece"></td>
            <td>RIGHT BOX</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The text in the box is not centered, and the middle divder does not stay in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Simply add following properties and can change width and height of div according to design you requires:

```
.faketab td{
      float:left;
      width:45%;
      border:1px solid #000;
      height:100px;
    }
    .centerpiece{
      width:3% !important;
      float:left !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use 'flex-direction' and padding for the class called **'faketab table tr td'**

**HTML**

```
<div class="faketab">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>LEFT BOX</td>
                <td class="centerpiece"></td>
                <td>RIGHT BOX</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.faketab
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: horizontal;
    -moz-flex-direction: horizontal;
    -ms-flex-direction: horizontal;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    border-color: #b2b2b2;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #b2b2b2, #b2b2b2 50%, transparent 50%);
    color: #4d4d4d;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 49px; */
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    background-size: 0; 
} 
.faketab table tr td {
    width: 1em;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size:18px;
    flex-direction:row; 
    padding:0 50px 0 10px; /* this */ 
}
.centerpiece{
    border-left: 0.1em solid black;
}
```